# Use the results of two Guava ListenableFutures of different types

Tags: java, guava, future

I have two ListenableFutures which are completed on other threads. Each future is of a different type, and I wish to use both of their results when they are both complete.

Is there an elegant way to handle this using Guava?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Runnable listener = new Runnable() {
    private boolean jobDone = false;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        if (jobDone || !(future1.isDone() && future2.isDone())) {
            return;
        }
        jobDone = true;
        // TODO do your job
    }
};
future1.addListener(listener);
future2.addListener(listener);
```

Not really elegant, but should do the job.

Or, more elegant, but you'll need casts:

```
ListenableFuture<List<Object>> composedFuture = 
    Futures.allAsList(future1, future2);
```

Comment: Thanks! A third (but also inelegant) soultion is to add a callback to each future that checks if the other is done, and if so will do the job.

Answer (score 9):

If you want some sort of type safety you can do the following:

```
class Composite {
  public A a;
  public B b;
}

public ListenableFuture<Composite> combine(ListenableFuture<A> futureA, 
                                           final ListenableFuture<B> futureB) {

  return Futures.transform(futureA, new AsyncFunction<A, Composite>() {
    public ListenableFuture<Composite> apply(final A a) throws Exception {
      return Futures.transform(futureB, new Function<B, Compisite>() {
        public Composite apply(B b) {
          return new Composite(a, b);
        }
      }
    } 
  }

}

ListenableFuture<A> futureA = ...
ListenableFuture<B> futureB = ...

ListenableFuture<Composite> result = combine(futureA, futureB);
```

In this case `Composite` can be a `Pair<A, B>` from Apache Commons if you like.

Also, a failure in either future will result in a failure in the resulting combined future.

Another solution would be to take a look at [Trickle](https://github.com/spotify/trickle) from the team at Spotify. The GitHub README has an example which shows a solution to a similar problem.

There are undoubtedly other solutions but this is the one that popped into my head.

Answer (score 1):

Since Guava v20.0 you can use:

```
ListenableFuture<CombinedResult> resultFuture =
   Futures.whenAllSucceed(future1, future2)
       .call(callableThatCombinesAndReturnsCombinedResult, executor);
```

Look at [java docs example here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.FutureCombiner.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want some type safety, you can combine result of 2 different independent tasks by using `EventBus` from the sister Guava `com.google.common.eventbus` package

For the example sake, let's assume that one of you `Futures` returns `Integer` and the other `Double`.

First, create an accumulator (other names *builder*, *collector*, etc) class that you will register as an event sink with EventBus. As you can see it's really a POJO which will hanlde `Integer` and `Double` events

```
class Accumulator
{
    Integer intResult;
    Double  doubleResult;

    @Subscribe // This annotation makes it an event handler
    public void setIntResult ( final Integer val )
    {
        intResult = val;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void setDoubleResult ( final Double val )
    {
        doubleResult = val;
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the method that will take 2 futures and will combine them into an accumulator.

```
final ListenableFuture< Integer > future1 = ...;
final ListenableFuture< Double > future2 = ...;

final ImmutableList< ListenableFuture< ? extends Object> > futures =
    ImmutableList.< ListenableFuture<? extends Object> >of( future1, future2 );

final ListenableFuture< Accumulator > resultFuture =
    Futures.transform(
        // If you don't care about failures, use allAsList
        Futures.successfulAsList( futures ),
        new Function< List<Object>, Accumulator > ( )
        {
            @Override
            public Accumulator apply ( final List< Object > input )
            {
                final Accumulator accumulator = new Accumulator( );

                final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus( );
                eventBus.register( accumulator );

                for ( final Object cur: input )
                {
                    // Failed results will be set to null
                    if ( cur != null )
                    {
                        eventBus.post( cur );
                    }
                }

                return accumulator;
            }
        }
    );

final Accumulator accumulator = resultFuture.get( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that would perform the addition of 2 listenable futures:

```
//Asynchronous call to get first value
final ListenableFuture<Integer> futureValue1 = ...;

//Take the result of futureValue1 and transform it into a function to get the second value
final AsyncFunction<Integer, Integer> getSecondValueAndSumFunction = new AsyncFunction<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Integer> apply(final Integer value1) {

        //Asynchronous call to get second value
        final ListenableFuture<Integer> futureValue2 = ...;


        //Return the sum of the values
        final Function<Integer, Integer> addValuesFuture = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer value2) {

                Integer sum = value1 + value2;
                return sum;
            }               
        };              

        //Transform the second value so its value can be added to the first
        final ListenableFuture<Integer> sumFuture = Futures.transform(futureValue2, addValuesFuture);   

        return sumFuture;
    }
};

final ListenableFuture<Integer> valueOnePlusValueTwo = Futures.transform(futureValue1, getSecondValueAndSumFunction);
```