# Compose variable number of ListenableFuture

Tags: java, android, guava

I'm quite new to Futures and am stuck on chaining calls and create a list of objects. I'm using Android, API min is 19.

I want to code the method `getAllFoo()` below:

```
ListenableFuture<List<Foo>> getAllFoo() {
    // ...    
}
```

I have these 2 methods available:

```
ListenableFuture<Foo> getFoo(int index) {
    // gets a Foo by its index
}

ListenableFuture<Integer> getNbFoo() {
    // gets the total number of Foo objects
}
```

Method [`Futures.allAsList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(java.lang.Iterable)) would work nicely here, but my main constraint is that each call to `getFoo(int index)` cannot occur until the previous one is completed.

As far as I understand it (and tested it), [`Futures.allAsList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(java.lang.Iterable)) "fans-out" the calls (all the calls start at the same time), so **I can't use** something like that:

```
ListenableFuture<List<Foo>> getAllFoo() {
    // ...

    List<ListenableFuture<Foo>> allFutureFoos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        allFutureFoos.add(getFoo(i));
    }

    ListenableFuture<List<Foo>> allFoos = Futures.allAsList(allFutureFoos);

    return allFoos;
}
```

I have this kind of (ugly) solution (that works):

```
// ...
final SettableFuture<List<Foo>> future = SettableFuture.create();

List<Foo> listFoos = new ArrayList<>();
addApToList(future, 0, nbFoo, listFoos);

// ...
private ListenableFuture<List<Foo>> addFooToList(SettableFuture future, int idx, int size, List<Foo> allFoos) {

    Futures.addCallback(getFoo(idx), new FutureCallback<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Foo foo) {
            allFoos.add(foo);
            if ((idx + 1) < size) {
                addFooToList(future, idx + 1, size, allFoos);
            } else {
                future.set(allFoos);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            future.setException(throwable);
        }
    });
    return future;
}
```

How can I implement that elegantly using `ListenableFuture` ?

I found multiple related topics (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763443/use-the-results-of-two-guava-listenablefutures-of-different-types) or [that](http://blog.robotninjas.org/2013/05/07/composing-listenablefutures/)), but these are using "coded" transform, and are not based on a variable number of transformations.

How can I compose `ListenableFutures` and get the same return value as `Futures.allAsList()`, but by chaining calls (fan-in)?

Thanks !

Comment: After reading your question three times I still don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: English is not my native language, and I may have been a little heavy on phrasing. I'm editing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, it's better to chain derived futures together with `transform`/`catching`/`whennAllSucceed`/`whenAllComplete` than with manual `addListener`/`addCallback` calls. The transformation methods can do some more for you:

- present fewer opportunities to forget to set an output, thus hanging the program
- propagate cancellation
- avoid retaining memory longer than needed
- do tricks to reduce the chance of stack overflows

Anyway, I'm not sure there's a particularly elegant way to do this, but I suggest something along these lines (untested!):

```
ListenableFuture<Integer> countFuture = getNbFoo();
return countFuture.transformAsync(
    count -> {
      List<ListenableFuture<Foo>> results = new ArrayList<>();
      ListenableFuture<?> previous = countFuture;
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        ListenableFuture<Foo> current = previous.transformAsync(
            unused -> getFoo(index),
            directExecutor());
        results.add(current);
        previous = current;
      }
      return allAsList(results);
    },
    directExecutor());
```

Comment: I tried to translate your code into my thingy, but got an error on the `results.add(current)`.
At the end, you are using `allAsList(results)`, so won't all calls to `getFoo(index)` start when this point is reached? Or will the transformAsync get care of the chaining ?

Comment: Sorry, made a couple fixes. If it's still broken, I promise to actually compile it next time.... Yes, `transformAsync` will make sure that only one `getFoo` call happens at once. Normally this is obviously true: The transformation can't start until it knows what input value it's transforming. Here, it's more subtle: We're ignoring the input value (named `unused` above), but the "transformation" still won't start until we know that value.

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thanks @Chris Povirk for the edit and support :)